# LDAP Groups in authconfig

Tags: centos, redhat, ldap, authentication

In my authconfig setup, I always use :

```
--ldapbasedn='ou=users,o=Directory'
```

I thought by using:

```
--ldapbasedn='o=Directory'
```

groups would also be included, but no luck.

My LDAP schema looks like this:

[image: LDAP schema: o=Directory (2), ou=groups(2) ...]

But it doesn't seem that this includes group information.

[image: LDAP admin - cn=hadoop]

What's the idiomatic way to include group information into authconfig?

Answer (score 0):

I use ldap with a manual config, not using authconfig. Note this is not redhat/centos, but ubuntu and debian, but the config many be similar. (I use pam_ldap and nss_ldap)

I have a line in the ldap.conf which looks like this :
nss_base_group ou=group, o=*Mydirectory*

Comment: thanks ............ any details on how the base_group parameter works?